# Jquery's promise() - aggregate resolve values?

Tags: jquery, promise

I have an array of N deferreds :

```
var g=[];
var d=$.Deferred();
  g.push(d);

var d=$.Deferred();
  g.push(d);
```

After a while , they are being resolved :

```
setTimeout(function (){g[0].resolve(1);},1000);
setTimeout(function (){g[1].resolve(2);},2000);
```

When all of them are resolved : I want to display the sum of resolve values :

```
$.when.apply($,g).done(function (sum){console.log(sum)});
```

However  - `function (sum){...` signature is only for the first order or reslove so i will get here only 1.

If I want to get the `2` - I should use : `function (sum1,sum2){`...

And this is my exact problem. I don't want to write `` `function (sum1,sum2,.....){ ``...

What is the right way to do it ?

**[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/faruf/2/edit)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

```
$.when.apply($, g).done(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i])
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3RsdQ/)

Comment: I thought about this , and then I thought that I can use the `apply` also here.

Comment: @RoyiNamir sorry, I didn't get you... what is the problem you faced while using `arguments`

Comment: No problem . just thought to myself that I can use the `apply` here also.

Comment: Just wondering : what if I have 100 items to wait for ? would the array would be in size 100 ? is there any alternative ( no real case - just asking).

Comment: not as far as I know.... but this will still work... only problem is it will wait for all 100 items to finish..

Comment: @RoyiNamir if there are 100 items how do you want this to work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47110/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-royi-namir)